# If current week has missing value, how to replace it with the value from previous week?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that shows how much was paid ("`cenoz`" - cents per ounce) per product category during specific week and in a specific store.

```
clear
set more off
input week  store   cenoz   category
        1      1      2         1
        1      1      4         2
        1      1      3         3
        1      2      5         1
        1      2      7         2
        1      2      8         3
        2      1      4         1
        2      1      1         2
        2      1      10        3
        2      2      3         1
        2      2      4         2
        2      2      7         3
        3      1      5         1
        3      1      3         2
        3      2      5         1
        3      2      4         2
end
```

I create a new variable `cenoz3` that indicates how much on average was paid for category 3 given specific week and a store. Same with cenoz1, and cenoz2.

```
egen cenoz1 = mean(cenoz/ (category == 1)), by(week store) 
egen cenoz2 = mean(cenoz/ (category == 2)), by(week store) 
egen cenoz3 = mean(cenoz/ (category == 3)), by(week store)
```

It turns out that category 3 was not sold in any of the stores (1 and 2) in week 3. As a result, missing values are generated.

```
week    store   cenoz   category    cenoz1  cenoz2  cenoz3
  1       1       2        1           2       4      3
  1       1       4        2           2       4      3
  1       1       3        3           2       4      3
  1       2       5        1           5       7      8
  1       2       7        2           5       7      8
  1       2       8        3           5       7      8
  2       1       4        1           4       1      10
  2       1       1        2           4       1      10
  2       1       10       3           4       1      10
  2       2       3        1           3       4      7
  2       2       4        2           3       4      7
  2       2       7        3           3       4      7
  3       1       5        1           5       3      .
  3       1       3        2           5       3      .
  3       2       5        1           5       4      .
  3       2       4        2           5       4      .
```

I would like to replace missing values of a particular week with values of the previous week and matching store. That's to say:

```
replace missing values for category 3 in week 3 in store 1 
           with values for category 3 in week 2 in store 1
```

and

```
replace missing values for category 3 in week 3 in store 2 
           with values for category 3 in week 2 in store 2
```

Can I use command `replace` or is it something more complicated than that?

Something like:

```
replace cenoz1 = cenoz1[_n-1] if missing(cenoz1)
```

But I also need to the stores to match, not just the time variable `week`.

I found this code provided by Nicholas Cox at
http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/:

```
by id (time), sort: replace myvar = myvar[_n-1] if myvar >= .
```

Do you think

```
 by store (week), sort: cenoz1 = cenoz1[_n-1] if missing(cenoz1)
```

is sufficient?

**UPDATE**:

When I use the code

```
by store (week category), sort: replace cenoz3 = cenoz3[_n-1] if missing(cenoz3)
```

It seems it delivers correct values:

```
week    store   cenoz   category    cenoz1  cenoz2  cenoz3
  1       1       2        1           2       4      3
  1       1       4        2           2       4      3
  1       1       3        3           2       4      3
  1       2       5        1           5       7      8
  1       2       7        2           5       7      8
  1       2       8        3           5       7      8
  2       1       4        1           4       1      10
  2       1       1        2           4       1      10
  2       1       10       3           4       1      10
  2       2       3        1           3       4      7
  2       2       4        2           3       4      7
  2       2       7        3           3       4      7
  3       1       5        1           5       3      10
  3       1       3        2           5       3      10
  3       2       5        1           5       4      7
  3       2       4        2           5       4      7
```

Is there any way to double check this code given that my dataset is quite large?

How make this code not so specific but applicable to any missing `cenoz` if it finds one with missing vaues? `(cenoz1, cenoz2, cenoz3, cenoz4...cenoz12)`

Comment: Yes, you can probably include `replace` somewhere in your solution. What have you tried specifically? On another note, your `egen, mean()`s are not computing means. I mean, they are, but for only one observation for `week store` groups. Is this a feature of your example data or would this be true for your real database? Is it what you intend?

Comment: My dataset has 97,000 observations such that each week store group has multiple observations that belong to a same category. I just didn't want to make the sample too long.

Comment: Please see an update at the end of the post.

Comment: You want `store`s **and** `categor`ies to match so I believe you're missing something (but almost there). Have you not tried your own code to see if it is sufficient? Just give it a try and check the results. If you have any problem, update your question.

Comment: You need a `replace` in your last statement.

Comment: Please see an update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the previous information for the same store and the same category, that should be

```
by store category (week), sort: replace cenoz3 = cenoz3[_n-1] if missing(cenoz3)
```

A generalization could be

```
sort store category week 
forval j = 1/12 { 
    by store category: replace cenoz`j' = cenoz`j'[_n-1] if missing(cenoz`j') 
}
```

However this carrying forward is a fairly crude method of interpolation. Consider linear, cubic, cubic spline, PCHIP methods of interpolation. Use `search` to find Stata programs.

Comment: Nick, I was trying to find information about the order of variables in a BY/SORT command but couldn't. Do the following codes produce identical information: _by **store category** (week), sort: replace cenoz3 = cenoz3[_n-1] if missing(cenoz3)_ and _by **category store** (week), sort: replace cenoz3 = cenoz3[_n-1] if missing(cenoz3)_? And what is with the parenthesis? Can you point at a source where I can read about what happens when we change the variables' order of appearance for different combination of variables? Additiona information about parenthesis in this context will be great too.

Comment: Those statements are equivalent. The parentheses are explained in the help for `by` which is where you should **always** start reading. If your search strategy is to start with Google, that's common but quite the wrong way round.

Comment: Consider a simple case in which `foo` has values `frog toad` and `bar` has values `red black`. Then the cross-combinations of `bar foo` are just `"red frog" "red toad" "black frog" "black toad"` and the cross-combinations of `foo bar` are the same but presented in a different order. So the order of groups is just a matter of order, not definition. But within groups, the order of observations can matter, as it does for this problem, when you use previous values.

Comment: Hello Nick. Your answer to my posting worked very well. However, not all observations were replaced with the values of the previous week/store/category. I thought that it might be because there was no previous week to refer to but it was not the case. I apologize for delay in my answer: I have been juggling a couple of projects simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

A quick note on why your code

```
by store (category week), sort: replace cenoz3 = cenoz3[_n-1] if missing(cenoz3)
```

won't work.

It will work for the example dataset you give. But a slight modification can give unexpected results. Consider the following example:

```
clear all
set more off

input week  store   cenoz   category
        1      1      2         1
        1      1      4         2 /* 
        1      1      3         3 deleted observation */
        1      2      5         1
        1      2      7         2
        1      2      8         3
        2      1      4         1
        2      1      1         2
        2      1      10        3
        2      2      3         1
        2      2      4         2
        2      2      7         3
        3      1      5         1
        3      1      3         2
        3      1    999          3 // new observation
        3      2      5         1
        3      2      4         2
end 

egen cenoz1 = mean(cenoz/ (category == 1)), by(week store) 
egen cenoz2 = mean(cenoz/ (category == 2)), by(week store) 
egen cenoz3 = mean(cenoz/ (category == 3)), by(week store) 

order store category week
sort store category week
list, sepby(store category)

*----- method 1 (your code) -----

gen cenoz3x1 = cenoz3
by store (category week), sort: replace cenoz3x1 = cenoz3x1[_n-1] if missing(cenoz3x1) 

*----- method 2 (Nick's code) -----

gen cenoz3x2 = cenoz3
by store category (week), sort: replace cenoz3x2 = cenoz3x2[_n-1] if missing(cenoz3x2) 

list, sepby(store category)
```

Method 1 will assign the price of a **category 1** article to a **category 2** article (observation 4 of `cenoz3x1`). Presumably, something you don't want. If you want to avoid this, then the groups should be based on `store category` and not just `store`.

The best place to start reading is `help` and the manuals.

Comment: Hi Roberto, sorry I forgot to follow up. Thanks for your feedback. Right after you posted it, I ran the codes several times and both of the codes produces the same result for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure if you refer two both "methods" I describe in my post, but if you are, the purpose of the example is to show that they _will give different results, even if in some particular application they don't_. It's not clear if Nick's solution worked for you. I presume it did. If so, consider "accepting" his answer.

Comment: Roberto, thank you, I see your point. I have also added a commentary to Nick's feedback.